# ASP.NET Membership Roles

Tags: asp.net, mysql, asp.net-membership, sql-like

I am trying to add user to some role and I am getting 'User is already in role.', the user actually not in any role, I traced the query which ran behind Roles.IsUserInRole(user_name) and its like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_aspnet_usersinroles uir 
JOIN my_aspnet_users u ON uir.userId=u.id
JOIN my_aspnet_roles r ON uir.roleId=r.id
WHERE u.applicationId=1 AND 
u.name LIKE 'user_name' AND r.name LIKE 'rolename'
```

now the problem is that I have another user (user.name) and this user already in that role, but because of (_) in like pattern am getting this result.
note that I am using MySql membership provider, any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to escape the underscore character with [] or the ESCAPE clause (better for your case.)

http://web.archive.org/web/20150519072547/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-do-i-search-for-special-characters-e-g-in-sql-server.html

Pardon the SQL2000 reference...

Answer (score 0):

The underscore in a LIKE clause acts as a wild card, so ANY character at that position will match.

If you are looking for a specific record, why not do WHERE u.name = 'user_name' ?

Comment: yes, but the membership Roles.IsUserInRole searches the database using (like) not (=), so am not looking for the record manually.

Comment: @Neil I think the problem here is that the OP has not overridden the default membership provider, so `IsUserInRole` is probably calling a stored procedure (in Microsoft's `aspnetdb` database)  that executes the query listed in the question.  LesterDove's answer provides a decent workaround if he doesn't want to modify the sp or override the membership provider.

Comment: (Sorry for that excessively long comment)

Comment: I can escape the _ in this case by IsUserInRole(user_name.Replace(_, \\_)), but my concerns now about the rest of membership default methods and am wondering why the provider uses Like, I tried also to update the comment of (user_name) and (user.name) got updated too!